# PHP OOP Script using Multithreading, terminates unexpectedly

Tags: php, multithreading, oop

Hi I'm having a problem trying to get threads to perform properly. The problem is that my php script will terminate unexpectedly at 1 of 2 specific points, during execution, and works the rest of the time.

**I've created a test scenario that produces the same result:**

This script creates 5 threads. Each thread adds up, each iteration, of a random number ranging from 10 to 20.

Secondly, Summary_Thread checks to see when all threads are completed before printing the summary... and there in lies the issue.

The script terminates during Summary_Thread::run and Stack_Item_Container_Stack::Compile_Summary, which is indirectly called at the end of Summary_Thread::run.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ignore_user_abort();

class Summary_Thread_Container
{
    public $stack_item_container_stack;
    private $summary_thread;

    function __construct($thread_count, Stack_Item_Container_Stack $stack_item_container_stack)
    {
        $this->stack_item_container_stack = $stack_item_container_stack;

        $this->summary_thread = new Summary_Thread($thread_count, $this);
        $this->summary_thread->start();
    }

    public function Compile_Summary(){ $this->stack_item_container_stack->Compile_Summary(); }
}

class Summary_Thread extends Worker
{
    private $summary_thread_container;
    private $thread_count;

    function __construct($thread_count, Summary_Thread_Container $summary_thread_container)
    {
        $this->summary_thread_container = $summary_thread_container;
        $this->thread_count = $thread_count;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $thread_count = 0;

        echo "\n**************************************  Stack Thread Count: {$this->thread_count} \n";

        echo "*** START.\n";

        if($this->thread_count == $thread_count)
            echo "*** THREAD COUNTS MATCH.\n";
        else
            echo "*** THREAD COUNTS DO NOT MATCH.\n";

        while($this->thread_count != $thread_count)
        {
            $temp_SIC = $this->summary_thread_container->stack_item_container_stack->first_stack_item_container;
            $thread_count = 0;

            while($temp_SIC)
            {
                $thread_count++;

                echo "**************************************  Thread Count: {$thread_count} \n";

                $temp_SIC = $temp_SIC->Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container();
            }

            echo "*** END.\n";

            if($this->thread_count == $thread_count)
                echo "*** THREAD COUNTS MATCH.\n";
            else
                echo "*** THREAD COUNTS DO NOT MATCH.\n";
        }

        $this->Compile_Summary();
    }

    public function Compile_Summary(){ $this->summary_thread_container->Compile_Summary(); }
}

class Stack_Item_Container_Stack
{
    public $first_stack_item_container;
    private $thread_count;
    private $summary_thread_container;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->first_stack_item_container = null;
        $this->thread_count = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
        {
            echo "       * Creating Stack Item Container: {$i}\n";

            $this->thread_count++;
            $this->Add_Stack_Item_Container(new Stack_Item_Container(rand(10, 20), $i, $this));
        }

        $this->summary_thread_container = new Summary_Thread_Container($this->thread_count, $this);
    }

    public function Add_Stack_Item_Container(Stack_Item_Container $stack_item_container)
    {
        echo "       * Adding Stack Item Container *\n";

        if($this->first_stack_item_container)
        {
            $temp_stack_item_container = $this->first_stack_item_container;

            while($temp_stack_item_container->Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container())
                $temp_stack_item_container = $temp_stack_item_container->Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container();

            $temp_stack_item_container->Set_Next_Stack_Item_Container($stack_item_container);
        }
        else $this->first_stack_item_container = $stack_item_container;
    }

    public function Compile_Summary()
    {
        echo "\n";
        echo "===============\n";
        echo "=== Summary ===\n";
        echo "===============\n";
        echo "\n";

        $temp_SIC = $this->first_stack_item_container;

        while($temp_SIC)
        {
            echo "    Thread ID {$temp_SIC->member_variables[0]} ({$temp_SIC->member_variables[4]}) has a Total of {$temp_SIC->member_variables[2]}";
            echo "\n";

            $temp_SIC = $temp_SIC->Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container();
        }

        echo "\n";

        $this->Kill();
    }

    private function Kill()
    {
        while($this->first_stack_item_container)
        {
            $temp_SIC = $this->first_stack_item_container;

            $this->first_stack_item_container = $this->first_stack_item_container->Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container();

            $temp_SIC->Kill();
        }

        unset($this->summary_thread_container);
        unset($this);
    }
}

class Stack_Item_Container
{
    private $stack_item_container_stack;
    private $next_stack_item_container;

    public $member_variables;

    public $stack_item_thread;

    function __construct($time, $index, Stack_Item_Container_Stack $stack_item_container_stack)
    {
        $this->stack_item_container_stack = $stack_item_container_stack;
        $this->next_stack_item_container = null;

        $this->member_variables = new Stackable();
        $this->member_variables[] = -1;
        $this->member_variables[] = $time;
        $this->member_variables[] = 0;
        $this->member_variables[] = false;
        $this->member_variables[] = $index;

        $this->stack_item_thread = new Stack_Item_Thread($this->member_variables, $this);
        $this->stack_item_thread->start();
    }

    public function Get_Stack_Item_Container_Stack(){ return $this->stack_item_container_stack; }

    public function Get_Next_Stack_Item_Container(){ return $this->next_stack_item_container; }
    public function Set_Next_Stack_Item_Container(Stack_Item_Container $next_SIC){ $this->next_stack_item_container = $next_SIC; }

    public function Kill()
    {
        $this->stack_item_thread->kill();
        unset($this->member_variables);
        unset($this);
    }
}

class Stack_Item_Thread extends Worker
{
    private $stack_item_container;
    private $member_variables;

    function __construct($member_variables, Stack_Item_Container $stack_item_container)
    {
        $this->member_variables = $member_variables;
        $this->stack_item_container = $stack_item_container;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->member_variables[0] = $this->getThreadId();
        $total = 0;

        echo "\n";

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->member_variables[1]; $i++)
        {
            $total += $i;
            $val = $i + 1;

            echo "Thread ID ({$this->member_variables[4]}): {$this->member_variables[0]}:";
            echo " Count: {$val} of {$this->member_variables[1]}";
            echo "\n";
        }

        echo "\n";

        $this->member_variables[2] = $total;
        $this->member_variables[3] = true;
    }
}

$stack_item_container_stack = new Stack_Item_Container_Stack();
```

OUTPUT 1 (When it does work):

```
**************************************  Stack Thread Count: 5
*** START.
*** THREAD COUNTS DO NOT MATCH.
**************************************  Thread Count: 1
**************************************  Thread Count: 2
**************************************  Thread Count: 3
**************************************  Thread Count: 4
**************************************  Thread Count: 5
*** END.
*** THREAD COUNTS MATCH.

===============
=== Summary ===
===============

    Thread ID 139975400195840 (0) has a Total of 105
    Thread ID 139975389705984 (1) has a Total of 153
    Thread ID 139975378360064 (2) has a Total of 153
    Thread ID 139975367014144 (3) has a Total of 55
    Thread ID 139975130801920 (4) has a Total of 153
```

OUTPUT 2: (the first point that it will terminate):

```
**************************************  Stack Thread Count: 5
*** START.
*** THREAD COUNTS DO NOT MATCH.
```

OUTPUT 3: (the second point that it will terminate)

```
**************************************  Stack Thread Count: 5
*** START.
*** THREAD COUNTS DO NOT MATCH.
**************************************  Thread Count: 1
**************************************  Thread Count: 2
**************************************  Thread Count: 3
**************************************  Thread Count: 4
**************************************  Thread Count: 5
*** END.
*** THREAD COUNTS MATCH.
```

Just to give you as much information as i can:
(might not be relevant but just in case)

### Changes made to config:

File: /etc/sysctl.conf, Changes Made: net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10

File: php.ini, Changes Made: extension=php_pthreads.dll

### Server:

Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64

PHP 5.5.13

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

Max Requests    Per Child: 4000 - Keep Alive: off - Max Per Connection: 100

Timeouts        Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 15

Virtual Server  No

---

Please help :) and questions would help ... anything i'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant test it myself, but if PHP exits normaly without errors its propably caused by the main thread exiting before any other thread could finish. Try Thread::join them (http://php.net/manual/en/thread.join.php) so the parent thread waits until they are finished.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that sounds like the right path.